# Retrieving items with jQuery .autocomplete won't work, nor throw any error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to make .autocomplete work,a dn for some reason it doesn't show any items as it should, and the console is not showing any errors.

### This is what I have at my footer:

**(jquery-3.3.1.min.js and jquery UI 1.12.1)**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" ></script>
<script src='//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js'></script>
<script src="/js/tinymce.js"></script>
<script src="/js/autocompletar/autocompletar.js"></script>
```

### This is my html form:

```
<div class="form-group ui-widget">
<label for="userName">Tags existentes</label>
<div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
  <input type="tag" class="form-control" name="tag" id="tag" list="datalist">
</div>
  <div id="listado"></div>
</div>
```

### This is my .js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#tag" ).autocomplete({
        source: 'autocompletarTags.php',
        appendTo: "#listado",
        minLength: 2
     });
});
```

**I've also tried:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function(){
    $( "#tag" ).autocomplete({
        source: 'autocompletarTags.php',
        appendTo: "#listado",
        minLength: 2
     });
    });
});
```

**Please note that the files autocompletar.js and autocompletarTags.php are in the same folder.**

```
//php function to connect to DB
conectar(); 

//get search term
$tag = $_GET['term'];

$tags = $tag.'%';

$x = $conectarDB->prepare("
  SELECT nombre FROM tags
  WHERE nombre LIKE ?
  ORDER BY nombre ASC
  ");
$x->bindParam(1, $tags);
$x->execute();

if ($row = $x->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   foreach ($row as $value) {
        $data[] = $value['nombre'];
    }
}

//return json data
echo json_encode($data);

$conectarDB = NULL;
```

Any thoughts on why this is not working? I've followed the instructions [here](https://daveismyname.blog/autocomplete-with-php-mysql-and-jquery-ui) and I think that I've not forgotten any steps.

**UPDATE: The network panel status is 200 for each js file.**

**UPDATE 2: The output of json_encode($data) is `[" tag2"," tag3"," tag4","demo","demo2","tag1"]`** (which is actually the expected result)

**ANOTHER UPDATE:** IT DOES WORK WHEN THE JS SCRIPT IS EMBEDDED IN THE FILE.
Instead of adding it as a file reference at the very bottom, I've pasted the JS script at the very bottom of the file, and now it does work.

I've checked and the referenced file does appear at the very bottom of the page (I've checked the source of the page), so **why it does work only when is inline?**

Comment: what is the network panel saying? did it send a request? what was the response status code?

Comment: Didn't thought on checking on that, sorry, I've updated the question. What else is wrong with the question that received a -1 vote and a closing vote? I'm new to JS and I don't think that voting to close without a reason is nice. I though that the information given in the question was complete.

Comment: `$connectar = function(){//blah}` ? Or is it really `function connectar(){//blah}`. If the second way, remove the `$`

Comment: Thanks! What a silly error. Yes, it should be conectar()! Thanks. I've changed that (and I'll update the question, as still won't work)

Comment: Why you are using `JSON_HEX_APOS`? and what is your `$data` returns?

Comment: That constant was added to remove all ' that I may find. The $data variable retrieves all that's in the database: [" tag2"," tag3"," tag4","demo","demo2","tag1"]array(6) { [0]=> string(5) " tag2" [1]=> string(5) " tag3" [2]=> string(5) " tag4" [3]=> string(4) "demo" [4]=> string(5) "demo2" [5]=> string(4) "tag1" }

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, and I'm posting it here just in case it helps someone else in the future.

My problem was how I called the source. Even if both files were in the same folder, I should not just called it with the file name, but with the folder as well.

So, instead of:

```
source: 'autocompletarTags.php',
```

Should be:

```
source: '/my/folders/autocompletarTags.php',
```